# Show that for all $f$ and $g$ in $\mathbb{L}^1(E_n)$ that $f(\circ)g(x-\circ) \in \mathbb{L}^1(E_n)$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis

Show that for all $f$ and $g$ in $\mathbb{L}^1(E_n)$ that $f(\circ)g(x-\circ) \in \mathbb{L}^1(E_n)$ for a.e. $x \in E_n$.

I couldn't find this question elsewhere (it's difficult to search for as well).

---

We must show that $$ \int_{E_n} | f(t) g(x-t) | dt < \infty. $$

\begin{align}
   \mathrm{LHS} & = \int_{E_n} | f(t) g(x-t) | dt \\
                & \le \int_{E_n} | f(t)| | g(x-t)|  dt \\
                & \le \int_{E_n} | f(t)| \int_{E_n} | g(x-t)| dx  dt \quad \text{(not sure about this line)} \\
                & = \int_{E_n} | f(t)| dt \int_{E_n} | g(x-t)| dx \quad \text{by Fubini's theorem}\\
                & = \Vert f\Vert_1 \Vert g \Vert_1 \\
                & < \infty
\end{align}
as both $\Vert f\Vert_1$ and $\Vert g \Vert_1$ are finite.

---

Could someone confirm that the line I'm unsure of makes sense? If not (*or* if so) could you please explain why? I think it's true that $|g(x)| \le \Vert g \Vert_1$, $\forall x \in E_n$ since it's like saying that we add all the values $g$ can take and since $g(x)$ is in there, the inequality should hold.

Comment: You are right to be unsure about that line because it is not true. What you can try is the following: if you let $h(x) = \int\limits_{E_n}{|f(t)||g(x-t)| dt}$, then you are asked to show that $h(x)<\infty$ for a.e. $x\in E_n$. If you can show that $\int\limits_{E_n}{h(x) dx}<\infty$, then that suffices to show that $h(x)<\infty$ for a.e. $x\in E_n$.

Comment: $\int_{E_n} h(x) dx = \int_{E_n} \int_{E_n} |f(t)| |g(x-t)| dt dx = \int_{E_n} |f(t)| \int_{E_n} |g(x-t)| dx dt = \int_{E_n} |f(t)| \Vert g \Vert_1 dt = \Vert g \Vert_1 \int_{E_n} |f(t)| dt = \Vert g \Vert_1 \Vert f \Vert_1 < \infty$? Did you mean like that, where we use Fubini's theorem?

Comment: Yes, that's good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That line is not true.

To show that $h(x) = \int f(y)g(x-y)dy$ is an $L^1$ function, one can use the following trick:

> If $\int h(x) < \infty$, then $h(x)$ is finite a.e.

Now, do the following:
$$
\int h(x)dx = \int \int f(y)g(x-y) dydx \leq \int \int |f(y)||g(x-y)|dx dy
$$
Now, 
$$
\int \int |f(y)||g(x-y)|dx dy \leq  \int |f(y)| \int |g(x-y)|dx dy  
$$
Finally,
$$
\int |f(y)| \int |g(x-y)|dx dy  \leq \int |f(y)| dy \int |g(x-y)|dx \leq ||f||_1\cdot||g||_1
$$
Hence, we have that $h(x)$ is bounded a.e., which is the same thing as the convolution exists a.e.